# Selecting multiple items in two JTables

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Does anyone know how I would select a row in one `JTable` and then it would highlight a row in another `JTable`?

```
ListSelectionListener[] listeners = leftJTable.getListeners(ListSelectionListener.class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, two tables can share the same `ListSelectionModel`:

```
JTable left = new JTable(...);
JTable right = new JTable(...);
right.setSelectionModel(left.getSelectionModel());
```